# I saw this notice in a bank today. Is this an oxymoron?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

> Fresh coins / banknotes are available
>
> *Subject to availability

I know what they mean to say but shouldn't they be using some other word instead of `available` in the first part of the notice?

In computer programming that situation will call for an infinite recursion.

Comment: Yes, looks like a case of [CYA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_your_ass)-recursion.

Comment: I'm curious about what they mean by *fresh coins.* Perhaps 'newly harvested'? 'Straight out of the oven'? 'New designs'? 'Sprayed with room freshener'? 'Vivacious and flirtatious'? You'd think they would be a little more specific.

Comment: Aha, that can be another question too :) For the sake of this first question we can assume they meant freshly printed banknotes. Wonder what prompted them to say coins

Comment: Aha - 'Factory fresh', then. :)

Comment: _New coins / banknotes are usually available_ seems to be better phrased. An oxymoron is a compressed paradox: something appearing contradictory at first sight, but making sense when one analyses more deeply. But this example is just juxtaposing loose and strict definitions of 'available' etc in an unsatisfactory way.

Comment: I think this question may be off-topic because it's a peeve/invitation to discussion

Comment: The notice is certainly exhaustive, in the sense that it covers all possible situations. But I suppose that's true of any assertion that takes the form, "X is available. Or not."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't really that contradictory - the first line is advertizing a non-standard service, that of giving change in especially pretty notes and coins for gifts or some such.  Many banks will not do this, just giving change out of the till.

The second line just warns that this is a extra service that isn't always offered, so don't get upset as you might if you were refused service at a McDonalds.

Answer (score 2):

It's not an *oxymoron*, as it is not a phrase which contradicts itself.  It *is*, however, *redundant*, which may be the adjective you are looking for to describe this poorly-phrased sign.

It's likely a case of legalese boilerplate being tacked on to an already awkwardly-phrased sentence.  In America, a sign would typically make the first sentence much more forceful and then disclaim it with the footnote, as in:

> Fresh coins and banknotes can be purchased here*
>
> *Subject to availability